# WiFi only version iPad app?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, appstore-approval

I have an iPad that worked perfectly with my iPads with WiFi only environment.  But It was rejected due to one of the function that I suspected that the cellular network has something to do with it.  Currently, without the necessary resources to test in that environment, I want to target this app only for WiFi version of iPad.  Does anyone know if we can submit a WiFi only version app for iPad?

Answer (score -1):

Of course it's not possible, and it's not really reasonable. As a developer you want to have as large userbase as possible, so targeting only wifi iPad version would not serve you at all. Just test it thorougly on different device configurations, fix the bugs and submit again. If you have Mac OS X Lion, you could use Network Link Conditioner Utility for simulating lousy internet connection (3G/Edge). Don't underestimate the importance of testing on the real device though.

Comment: -1, a little late to this ballgame, but this is incorrect. You can build wifi only apps. I can agree you might not want to, but it is possible. Look at iSwifter in the store.